# How do I Get WiFi working on my Dell Inspiron 1501 with BCM4311 [14e4:4311]?

Tags: networking, dell, blacklist

My wireless doesn't work with Ubuntu 12.04.(it worked with 10.04 LTS) I have a Dell Inspiron 1501. I followed the steps posted below:

**Run these:**

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source`

`echo "blacklist brcmsmac" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

`echo "blacklist bcma" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

The first makes sure that the sta driver is in place, the second and third blacklists the two drivers brcmsmac and bcma which clash with the correct sta driver. Copy/paste or make sure your typing is correct!
The last step is to go to 'Additional drivers' and enable the driver.**

....and now i have no Network device on my PC(wired or wireless)

Comment: Can you add the hardware specs to the question - `lspci -nn | grep -i net`. Simply removing entries from /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf probably won't help.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same but I did answer the question ;) I came to the conclusion that it might be better to ask a new question on HOW to get wireless working. Purging the 1st command might not getting the desired results either :(

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the alterations from the last 2 commands with `vi`.

```
sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

And remove the lines that says

```
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma
```

---

Navigate with the arrow keys to those lines.
`dd` to remove a line.
`{escape}:wq` to save the alterations.

Comment: Thanks, i asked a new question with :how to...because removing the lines did not help. In my blacklist file, this two lines still appear ...

Comment: The hardware specs are:  05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c] (rev 02)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to also run:

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

and

```
echo "wl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

You see, the point is to black list bcma and brcmsmac and to use wl only instead.

---

However, for 4311 I believe you are supposed to do this instead:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
sudo modprobe b43
echo "b43" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BroadcomSTA%28Wireless%29

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to blacklist anything when you install `bcmwl-kernel-source`.

This package does it itself. And these blacklists are removed, when the package is removed.

You can also remove these lines by

```
 sudo sed -i '/blacklist brcmsmac/d' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
 sudo sed -i '/blacklist bcma/d' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, you should change the title of the question since you really want to get wireless working on your Dell Inspiron 1501 with BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311].

1. You will need to undo your blacklisting and my preferred way would be to use the terminal text editor nano so `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and delete the lines you added.
2. According to the [linuxwireless.org b43 page](http://www.linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/), you should be able to use the b43 driver and this is what I have had the most success with. So remove the packages you installed by running `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source`
3. Now you should be ready to install b43, so run `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`
4. Now simply reboot with your fingers crossed!